# Soma de totais de colunas

Tags: python

Possuo este dataset:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Gostaria de criar comando para somar os valores de cada ano, e colocar em uma lista.

```
  lista=[]
  for i in range(2008, 2041):
   area[i].sum()
    lista.append(i)
```

Mais não funcionou do jeito que fiz, gostaria de um auxílio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumi que você está usando pandas.

De qualquer jeito, partindo disto:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Distritos': ['Local1', 'Local2'], '2017': [30, 40], '2018': [50, 60]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
>>> print df
   2017  2018 Distritos
0    30    50    Local1
1    40    60    Local2
```

Pego os anos assim:

```
anos = list(df.columns.values)
anos.remove('Distritos')
>>> print anos
['2017', '2018']
```

Somar todas do mesmo ano:

```
lista = []
for ano in anos:
    lista.append(df[ano].sum())
>>> print lista
[70, 110]
```

Somar todos os valores de cada região:

```
lista = []
for i in range(len(df)): #para cada região
    soma = 0
    for ano in anos: #seleciono os anos
        soma += df.iloc[i][ano]
    lista.append(soma)
>>> print lista
[80, 100]
```

Comment: Não funcionou deste jeito

Comment: Mas eu fiz assim:

   `lista=[]
    for i in range(2008, 2021):
        tes=area[i].sum()
        lista.append(tes)`

E funcionou, mas o problema é que no dataset depois de 2020 o intervalo fica de 5 e 5 e dá erro.

Comment: Veja agora com a edição que fiz...

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 0):

tente primeiro usar o for enquanto um dado existir.

```
lista = []
for i in arq:
    arq.split('?') #o '?' é o que separa cada índice no seu arquivo ou variável que contém a informação que quer
```

desta forma você tem linhas e colunas agora e o próximo passo é só ver qual o range do índice que você quer somar

```
i = 2
sum = 0
for i in range(n): #n tem que ser o numero de colunas que quer percorrer
 sum = sum + arq[i] 
lista.append(sum)
```

o código completo fica:

```
lista = []
for i in arq:
    arq.split('?')
    sum = 0
    for j in range(2,n): #n tem que ser o numero de colunas que quer percorrer
        sum = sum + arq[j] 
    lista.append(sum)
```